# Creating a union of columns based on metrics

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,4], 'b': [0,3,5],'c':[1,1,1,1]})

    a   b   c
0   1   0   1
1   2   3   1
2   4   5   1
```

and a list `[('a', 0.91), ('b', 5), ('c', 2)]`.

Now I want to create another dataframe which iterates through each row and multiplies df element and list element together and and then selects the top 2 scores and makes a new list which has the said column names.

for example in the first row we have-

```
1*0.9=0.9 , 0*5=0 , 1*2=2
```

therefore the top 2 columns are a and c so we append them to a new list.

second row-

```
2*0.9=1.8, 3*5=15,1*2=2
```

therefore `list=[a,c,b]`
and so on...

third row-

```
4*0.9=3.6,5*5=25,1*2=2
```

so list remains unchanged `[a,c,b]`

so final output is `[a,c,b]`

Comment: So what is exected output finally?

Comment: And the code you've tried so far?

Comment: I have added the expected output

Comment: I dont get how this can be the expected output if you want two columns from each row.

Comment: @ChristianSloper I have added the calculations also to show...I want the top two columns in each row based on the calculations...now if thar column is already present it wont be repeated

Comment: So there are list for each row? Why in first row are top2 and then for another `[a,c,b]` and again `[a,c,b]` ? Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael for the first row the scores I got for each column was 0.9,0,2..therefore the top 2 are 0.9 and 2 that is column a and c so I include them in a new list...then in second row I do the same and I get 1.8 ,15 that is column a and b..since a was already in the list I add b to the list [a,c] becoming [a,c,b] and so on

Comment: So after to iterations you have no other elements to add, is that right?? @ubuntu_noob

Comment: @yatu after the third iteration I find a,b to have highest score but since they are already in the list so I dont add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly I think the previous answers are incomplete so here is a solution. It involves using numpy which i hope you accept.

Create the weights:

```
n = [('a', 0.91), ('b', 5), ('c', 2)]
d = { a:b for a,b in n}
weights = [d[i] for i in df.columns]
```

Then we create a table with weights multiplied in:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,4], 'b': [0,3,5],'c':[1,1,1]})
df = df*weights
```

This yields:

```
a   b   c
0   0.9 0.0 2.0
1   1.8 15.0    2.0
2   3.6 25.0    2.0
```

Then we can get top two indices for this in numpy:

```
b = np.argsort(df.values,axis=1)
b = b[:,-2:]
```

This yields:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Finally we can calculate the order of appearance and give back column names:

```
c =b.reshape(-1)
_, idx = np.unique(c, return_index=True)
d = c[np.sort(idx)]
print(list(df.columns[d].values))
```

This yields:

```
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Comment: The weights are a list of tuples where the name of the column is specified. Not a list of values

Comment: @yatu changed to list output.  current output now match your expected output, can you change your post if this is not right?

Comment: I did not post the question. I'm just saying that `[0.9,5,2]` is not in the input data.  Instead `[('a', 0.91), ('b', 5), ('c', 2)]`. So I guess what makes sense is not to assume order in the columns, and use this list of tuples (you can make it a dict) to multiply the corresponding values

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dict1 = {'a':[1,2,4], 'b': [0,3,5],'c':[1,1,1]} # arrays must all be same length
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
list1 = [('a', 0.91), ('b', 5), ('c', 2)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({k : [j*v[1] for j in dict1[k]] for k in dict1 for v in list1 if k == v[0]})

"""
df2 should be like this :
     a   b  c
0  0.91   0  2
1  1.82  15  2
2  3.64  25  2
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need:

```
a = [('a', 0.91), ('b', 5), ('c', 2)]
m= df.mul(pd.DataFrame(a).set_index(0)[1])

      a     b    c
0  0.91   0.0  2.0
1  1.82  15.0  2.0
2  3.64  25.0  2.0
```

Applying rank on each row and taking the sum , then sorting and finding the index gives your desired output.

```
m.rank(axis=1,method='dense').sum().sort_values().index.tolist()
#['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Comment: my final output is list which contains the columns

Comment: @ubuntu_noob i had edited the answer, does it work now? :)